# Is there a POSIX pathname that can't name a file?

Tags: unix, path, filenames, file-location, posix

Are there any legal paths in POSIX that cannot be associated with a file, regular or irregular?  That is, for which `test -e "$LEGITIMATEPOSIXPATHNAME"` cannot succeed?

**Clarification #1: pathnames**

By "legal paths in POSIX", I mean ones that POSIX says are allowed, not ones that POSIX doesn't explicitly forbid.  I've looked this up, and the are POSIX specification calls them character strings that:

1. Use only characters from the portable filename character set `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]` (cf. http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276);
2. Do not begin with `-`; and
3. Have length between 1 and NAME_MAX, a number unspecified for POSIX that is not less than 14.

POSIX also allows that filesystems will probably be more relaxed than this, but it forbids the characters NUL and `/` from appearing in filenames.  Note that such a paradigmatically UNIX filename as `lost+found` isn't FPF, according to this def.  There's another constant PATH_MAX, whose use needs no further explanation.

The ideal answer will use FPFs, but I'm interested in any example with filenames that POSIX doesn't expressly forbid.

**Clarification #2: impossibility**

Obviously, pathnames normally could be bound to a file.  But UNIX semantics will tell you that there are special places that couldn't normally have arbitrary files created, like in the `/dev` directory.  Are any such special places stipulated in POSIX?  That is what the question is getting after.

Comment: Hmmm, I was wondering if that title couldn't be more descriptive, but whatever I come up with seems to yield a contradiction in terms...

Comment: Just a note...

it's not \ it's /. In Unix \ is a fine character to have in a file.
/user/chuck/tom\mary
the filename=tom\mary.

Comment: @DrFloyd: Right.  Fixed.

Comment: I like this question.  It reminds me of "Der Mouse", when moving from VMS to UNIX, being annoyed because he could not find a way to create a filename with a slash or a null in it - where the slash was part of the filename within a directory, rather than a separator between directory and something in the directory.  //   The standard POSIX APIs do not produce an error on such filenames, they simply interpret the embedded special characters as either path separate or string terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the final question is whether there are special places that couldn't normally have a file, like in the /dev directory stipulated in POSIX, then the andswer is **YES**.

The complete list of pre-determined files and directories is given in chapter 10, [POSIX Directory Structure and Devices](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html), of the [IEEE Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/toc.htm):

> The following directories shall exist
>   on conforming systems and conforming
>   applications shall make use of them
>   only as described. Strictly conforming
>   applications shall not assume the
>   ability to create files in any of
>   these directories, unless specified
>   below.
>
> **/**
>       The root directory.
>  **/dev**
>       Contains /dev/console, /dev/null, and /dev/tty, described below.
>
> The following directory shall exist on
>   conforming systems and shall be used
>   as described:
>
> **/tmp**
>       A directory made available for applications that need a place to
>   create temporary files. Applications
>   shall be allowed to create files in
>   this directory, but shall not assume
>   that such files are preserved between
>   invocations of the application.
>
> The following files shall exist on
>   conforming systems and shall be both
>   readable and writable:
>
> **/dev/null**
>       An infinite data source and data sink. Data written to /dev/null shall
>   be discarded. Reads from /dev/null
>   shall always return end-of-file
>   (EOF).
>  **/dev/tty**
>       In each process, a synonym for the controlling terminal associated with
>   the process group of that process, if
>   any. It is useful for programs or
>   shell procedures that wish to be sure
>   of writing messages to or reading data
>   from the terminal no matter how output
>   has been redirected. It can also be
>   used for applications that demand the
>   name of a file for output, when typed
>   output is desired and it is tiresome
>   to find out what terminal is currently
>   in use.
>
> The following file shall exist on
>   conforming systems and need not be
>   readable or writable:
>
> **/dev/console**
>       The /dev/console file is a generic name given to the system console (see
>   System Console). It is usually linked
>   to an implementation-defined special
>   file. It shall provide an interface to
>   the system console conforming to the
>   requirements of the Base Definitions
>   volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001,
>   Chapter 11, General Terminal
>   Interface.

Comment: I assume that the term "files" also includes directories, so in your example a POSIX program cannot also assume that it can create a directory named "impossible". The terminology used is a bit confusing, and I assume the the authors didn't imagine that /dev could contain directories.

Comment: `/dev` can and typically does contain directories: SunOS has had a fsfs mounted at `/dev/fd` for ages, and its copied by most modern UNIXes.  But POSIX forbids a file from being both a character special and a directory, so there can't be anything under `/dev/tty`.  So chosen: I have my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Testing for a filename with the null character in it should always fail.

POSIX reserves '/' and null from filenames. This is sensible: one is the directory separator, and one is a string terminator. To support that point, Wikipedia says ext2, ext3, and ext4 allow all bytes in filenames except null and the forward slash. NTFS, whether or not in POSIX-compatibility mode, disallows little more than that; and FAT variants also disallow null. In theory, it really depends on the file system. But I wouldn't hold my breath trying to find a case where null finds its way into a filename.

Comment: +1 for an answer that made me look something up.  POSIX forbids "/" and NUL in filenames.  Cf. my questions postscript.

Comment: What happens if you include the newline character or ASCII control codes in a file name?

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null/impossible` cannot exist. This is because `/dev/null` must be a file, and so cannot be a directory.

Same for `/dev/tty/impossible` and `/dev/console/impossible`

Answer (score 1):

"Legal path in POSIX" already means that it can point to a filesystem object (file, directory, symlink, etc).

On the second thought, some filesystems (such as FAT) have restrictions on allowed characters in filenames. So in my computer, `~/fs/phone/This:is*a?file|name.txt` would be rejected by the `vfat` filesystem driver.

---

To answer the second question, `test -e "$LEGITIMATEPOSIXPATHNAME"` fails when the file does not exist, obviously.

Comment: Hehe, +1 for that last paragraph. There is an answer to any question, I guess. :-)

Comment: s/fails/cannot succeed/

Comment: I am not familiar with any *nix where `/dev/fd/this-is-not-a-file` could be a file, but IIUC, POSIX doesn't say it couldn't be a file.  So being legal path in POSIX doesn't mean a POSIX-compliant OS must permit a file to be created there.

Comment: -1: Completely misses the point of the question.

Comment: @Charles, it kind of strikes me as odd that you're downvoting while I think your question was not clear at all to start with. (And *still* has a very bad title, which is not a question at all -- http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: @Arjan: Title changed.  Since people are misunderstanding it, I guess you must be right that it is not clear, but I do not see where the problem lies.  It takes the form "Is there an X that is Y", where the Xs are familiar, and the Y is precisely defined.

Answer (score 0):

The test would fail if the file-name breaks the limitations of the local implementation of POSIX.

Every file-system in existence makes assumptions as regarding maximum lengths, directory recursion limits and more. So a POSIX name that's legal on one operating system might not be legal on another.

So my answer to the question is "Yes":
Even names that are legal when tested on one POSIX system, may be rejected by another, because of implementation restrictions.

Comment: Every pathname that POSIX says is legal is accepted on all POSIX-compliant filesystems, by definition.  It is these that I care about.

Comment: Well, NAME_MAX and PATH_MAX are implementation-dependent. I think you're contradicting yourself when you ask (1) for unattainable POSIX file-names, and at the same time (2) accepted on all POSIX-compliant systems. By definition, acceptable file-names cannot be unattainable, and the least-common-denominator of all POSIX systems is always attainable on all of them.

Comment: Aha!  No, I want pathnames that would work, except that other assumptions in POSIX prevent the files from existing